# Mocking a method based on the parameter in Spock

Tags: groovy, spock

Im trying to figure out mocking and for some reason it keeps returning the correct answer (win) not the one i want it to return (mac)

```
/**
 * This is an empty imple class.  Its intention is to allow operating
 * system specific information to be mocked for unit testing.
 */
class OsImpl extends Os {

}


/**
 * A utility convenience class that helps with pulling a variety of machine information for the build system
 */
class ProjectInfo {
    static String operatingSystem(){
        operatingSystem(new OsImpl())
    }
    /**
     * Returns a 3 char code on the operating system of the local machine.
     * @return String Code ['win', 'mac', 'nix']
     */
    static String operatingSystem(OsImpl os){
        if (os.isFamily(os.FAMILY_WINDOWS)) {
            'win'
        } else if (os.isFamily(os.FAMILY_MAC)) {
            'mac'
        } else if (os.isFamily(os.FAMILY_UNIX)) {
            'nix'
        } else {
            null
        }
    }
}

class ProjectInfoTest extends Specification {

    def "trying this out"(){
        when:
        OsImpl os = Mock(OsImpl)

        and: 'mock a mac'
        1 * os.isFamily(os.FAMILY_WINDOWS) >> false
        1 * os.isFamily(os.FAMILY_MAC) >> true

        then: 'should return a mac os'
        ProjectInfo.operatingSystem(os) == 'mac'
    }
}
```

In easymock i would normally do a `when(...).return(...)` but im not sure how to do the same thing with spock.

Second try

```
def "trying this out"(){
        setup:
        OsImpl os = Mock(OsImpl)
        1 * os.isFamily(os.FAMILY_WINDOWS) >> false
        1 * os.isFamily(os.FAMILY_MAC) >> true

        when:
        String shouldBe = 'mac'

        then: 'should return a mac os'
        ProjectInfo.operatingSystem(os) == shouldBe
    }
```

Still returns windows, not mac

Heres another example of this.  I suppose i just suck at mocking.  But here's the method i want to test

```
def switchArtifactoryOffline(){
    def config = new XmlSlurper().parseText( artifactoryClient.system().configuration())
    if (config.offlineMode == false){
        config.offlineMode = true
        artifactoryClient.system().configuration(XmlUtil.serialize( config ))
    }
    log.lifecycle("Disabled Artifactory Internet Access")
}
```

and my test method

```
def "check that it switches artifactory offline"(){
    when:
    Artifactory arti = Mock(Artifactory)
    arti.system().configuration() >> "<client><offlineMode>false</offlineMode></client>"
    ArtifactoryWorker worker = new ArtifactoryWorker(arti)

    then:
    worker.switchArtifactoryOffline()
}
```

I keep getting a null on the system() object.  Now, in addition to mocking it out, how do i retrieve the value that the method put into `artifactoryClient.system().configuration(XmlUtil.serialize( config ))` so i can make sure that it actually did change the value and compiled the xml correctly?  This all seems pretty trivial stuff to me, i can't understand why im having such a problem with it.  Maybe I do need to switch back to mockito.

Ok, after messing around some more, i came up with this, and it seems to work, now back to the statics.....

```
def "check that it switches artifactory offline"(){
    given:
    Artifactory arti = Mock(Artifactory)
    ArtifactorySystem arti_system = Mock(ArtifactorySystem)

    arti_system.configuration() >> "<client><offlineMode>false</offlineMode></client>"
    arti.system() >> arti_system

    ArtifactoryWorker worker = new ArtifactoryWorker(arti)

    when:
    worker.switchArtifactoryOffline()

    then:
    1 * arti_system.configuration(_ as String) >> {
        def config = new XmlSlurper().parseText(it)
        assert config.offlineMode == true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Move the mocking statements down into your "then:" block.  Just keep them above the assertion.  The "and:" is what's tripping you up.  Mock callouts belong in the "setup/given" block or the "then" block.

Like so:

```
def "trying this out"(){
    setup:
    OsImpl os = Mock(OsImpl)

    expect: 'should return a mac os'
    1 * os.isFamily(os.FAMILY_WINDOWS) >> false
    1 * os.isFamily(os.FAMILY_MAC) >> true

    ProjectInfo.operatingSystem(os) == 'mac'
}
```

Comment: I tried that and it didn't work.  When i run your code, it errors saying os is not a property of the class.  I switched it to the code i just posted above and same deal, returns win instead of mac

Comment: @scphantm, there are multiple problems in your test - you want to test static methods and is this code written in java or in groovy?

Comment: OsImpl is groovy.  the object OsImpl extends is java, import org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.condition.Os